# Can I immediately skip to the next element in foreach loop, without a new iteration?

Tags: php, html

I wonder if I can proceed to next element/item in a foreach loop, *without* using `continue` (i.e. iterate to next element).

Here's an example of what I try to achieve. The array in the code below contains information on `divs` that should be generated. If the current element defines a class (i.e.  `class="myclass"`) it should be used, and the next element in the array should be fetched immediately and used as the div text.

**Edit:** The array has been corrected.

```
<?php
$arr = [”class” => ”my-class”, ”div text 1”, “div text 2”, “div text3”];

$html = "";
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == "class") {
        $class = "class='$value'";
        $value = goto_and_get_next_element();  // <-- this part should immediately fetch next element in loop, e.g. "div text 1" 
    } else {
        $class = "";
    }
    $html .= "<div {$class}>{$value}</div>\n";
}
?>
```

The result of $html above should be:

```
<div class="my-class">div text 1</div>
<div>div text 2</div>
<div>div text3</div>
```

I **am** aware of that I can use some "remember value" variables between each iteration and then use `continue`. I also know that I can "peek" on next values in the array by using `next()`. But my question is if there is some trick that moves to the next `$key => $value` immediately, without doing a new iteration?

Comment: Checkout `continue;` keyword

Comment: the array you shown is not possible as the `class` key will get over-written.: https://3v4l.org/qSKsF

Comment: @chovy I asked for a solution without using `continue`. I am aware that it may not be possible... but I'm curious if it's possible

Comment: @Gowire  did you read my comment?

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie Yes I saw it, and it took a while before I understood what you meant. But now I see my error. But if you ignore the second "class" key, or rename it... is it possible to do what I ask for? It seems that it won't be possible without using a continue statement....

Comment: If I were you I'd restructure that array to something like `$arr = [ ['text' => 'foo',], [ 'text' =>'bar', 'class' =>'my-class',],];`

Comment: @Gowire  the input array you shown is made by you or it coming from any third-party? Means to say do you have control over this array to restructure it?

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie The code is just an example to simplify (but with an error in this case). The "real" situation is data from a database query, where I want to iterate through columns and manage if a specific column is found (e.g. if a column called "class" is found, I wan't to grab that value and immediately move on to next column and use values there). My basic question is "Is it possible to move on to next item without using `continue`?"

Comment: @Gowire yes you can do there as its come in indexed form so you can go for `key+1` to get data and then unset it to move to next iteration

Comment: _'if a specific column is found (e.g. if a column called "class" is found, I wan't to grab that value and immediately move on to next column and use values there'_ - so _remember_ that value (we have super convenient things called "variables" for that), `continue` to the next iteration - and then there, based on that there _is_ a value you "remembered" from the previous iteration now, you should know what to do. _No need_ to "avoid" `continue`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to show: It is possible without `continue`.

```
<?php
$arr = ['class' => 'my-class', 'div text 1', 'div text 2', 'div text3'];
#create to arrays: key-array, value-array
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$values = array_values($arr);
#count the size
$s = count($values);
$html = "";
for ($i=0;$i<=$s;$i++) {
    #get your currrent data
    $key = $keys[$i];
    $value = $values[$i];
    if ($key == "class") {
        $class = "class='$value'";
        $value = $values[++$i];  #fetch the next value
        $s--;#decrease the size, because you used a value here
    } else {
        $class = "";
    }
    $html .= "<div {$class}>{$value}</div>\n";
}
print $html;
```

Now you get your expected output.